# jQuery .load() is not fired

Tags: jquery

In response to an event this is executed:

```
$.getScript('nav.php?node=' + node);
```

`nav.php` returns the following with correct headers (`'Content-type: application/javascript'`)

```
$('#uis').append('<div id="app-personal-games-ui"></div>',function() {
    $('#app-personal-games-ui').load('loadhtml.php', {from: 'app.personal.games.ui'})
);
app.personal.games = function() {
    activate('app-personal-games-ui');
};
app.personal.games();
```

What I am trying to acheive with the above code is:

1. append a wrapper `<div>` for the new content to `div id="uis">`
2. we set an `id` for the div just added, now use that id as a selector and load the actual html with `.load()`
3. add a function to our `app` object. this function would make the new div visible
4. execute the function added in step 3

The results show all steps complete successfully except for #2. i.e. `<div id="app-personal-games-ui"></div>` *is* added to the correct place, and `app.personal.games.toString();` in firebug shows the function is added to the object and has the correct code. But the `load` line does not get executed and the new div remains blank.

Why is this happening, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the `.append()` function doesn't take a callback. So you may try the following:

```
var query = { from: 'app.personal.games.ui' };
$('<div id="app-personal-games-ui"></div>').load('loadhtml.php', query, function() {
    $('#uid').append(this);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this would do it too (not passing a callback function append).

Answer (score 0):

I found what is wrong. What *really* is wrong is that I need some sleep, and still won't go to bed ;). But what is wrong with this script is that `.append()` does not take a callback function, and I should change the above to:

```
$('#uis').append('<div id="app-personal-games-ui"></div>');
$('#app-personal-games-ui').load('loadhtml.php', {from: 'app.personal.games.ui'});
```